# Populating html table nested in ul from php/json using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to populate a table nested in a list. The biggest problem is trying to parse a multi-line subquery from php in a json response. The php query fails because the subquery returns more than one record for each outer record, which is actually what I want.

Php is similar to:

```
SELECT application.name, application.document, application.department, 
application.title, (SELECT attachments.Attachment FROM attachments WHERE
attachments.nameid = participants.nameid) FROM application
INNER JOIN paricipants ON particpants.nameid = application.nameid
```

I've used GROUP_CONCAT to convert the subquery into a string, but can't send it back to jquery via json to populate my table nested in list.

I realise I might be going about this the wrong way, so I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You need just one Attachment, then use limit:

```
SELECT 
        application.name, 
        application.document, 
        application.department, 
        application.title, 
        (SELECT attachments.Attachment FROM attachments WHERE attachments.nameid = participants.nameid ORDER BY attachments.nameid DESC LIMIT 0,1) As ATTACHMENTS 
    FROM 
        application
        INNER JOIN paricipants 
        ON particpants.nameid = application.nameid
```

If You need all Attachments names then Concat_group or somethink else ..., but if You would like get attachments.nameid too then do 2 step require to Database and collect Attachments by PHP and return as Json.